# Is it true that light has a lot of energy but cannot exert force

Tags: visible-light

When a photon hits a mirror it is reflected ,it does not affect the mirror.But why when light has infinite energy?

Comment: *"infinite energy"* and *"Does not affect the mirror"* are baseless assertions. It's *unclear what you're asking*.

Comment: Why doesn't it affect the mirror?

Answer (score 1):

You're under a misconception. Photons can and do exert forces. A photon reflecting off of a perfect mirror can be modeled as an elastic collision. The momentum of the system is conserved, and the mirror moves in the opposite direction to the photon. The change in momentum of the mirror is because of the 'force' exerted by the photon. You can't observe this in every day life because mirrors are usually heavy and fixed, whereas photons posses an immensely small amount of momentum. (A visible light photon possesses momentum of the order $10^{-27}\mbox{ kg m s}^{-1}$, which is extremely small.)

Answer (score 1):

So for normal objects moving slowly, the energy-to-momentum ratio is $\frac 12 m v^2 / (m v) = \frac 12 v$. If you're sitting on an office chair with low-friction wheels and I want to get you moving by throwing tennis balls at you, the faster I throw them, the more "ow" you will feel (energy you'll dissipate) to get the same momentum.

For light, the energy-to-momentum ratio is **not** infinite, but it **is** very large: for light, $E / p = c$, the speed of light, which is 300,000 kilometers per second. The disappearance of the $\frac 12$ is actually a property of relativity, which extends the $\frac 12 v$ result to say that the "true" result for a particle moving at speed $v$ is actually $\frac{c^2}v\left(1 - \sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2}\right),$ which is $\frac 12 v$ for small $v$ but eventually gets all the way up to $c$ as $v \rightarrow c.$

So think of it basically as the fastest tennis ball there is, maximum sting per amount of momentum it gives you. It does exert forces, too -- this is how "light sails" can propel a ship away from the Sun -- but you really need to have good reflectors because the amount of energy you'll otherwise absorb is tremendous.

A good punch from a professional heavyweight boxer might contain, oh, say, on the order of $10,000 \text{ N}\cdot\text{s}$ of impulse. To do the same thing with light, let's say you're wearing a 99.99% reflective suit, then we only need to generate about half of that impulse as momentum-of-light (since the light goes the opposite direction after reflection), so the light contains $5,000\text{ N}\cdot\text{s}$ of momentum, which is 1.51 terajoules of energy. You absorb 1/10,000 of that, so 0.151 gigajoules of energy, over a little over a tenth of a second, on the order of gigawatts of energy.

If you've ever seen *Back to the Future* you know that this is the power scale of a bolt of lightning. So it's not just that you got punched by a heavyweight champion, but an amount of heat energy was dissipated into you as if you had been hit straight-on by a bolt of lightning. That's because even though your suit was so amazingly reflective, there was just so much energy in the light packet that hit you that you still got exposed to an unbelievable amount of it.